# What are ICS_R1 ICS_R2?

Tags: android

Time to update my SDKs... I launched SDK Manager thinking this would be a simple process but I am stumped by numerous options there.

[image]

For example, all I want is to be able to build and test against Android 4.0.3 (API 5), but in addition to the `SDK Platform` I see `ICS_R1` and `ICS_R2`. What are these? Do I need them?

Also, why doesn't Android 4.0.4 show up there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I see ICS_R1 and ICS_R2. What are these?

Those are the "Motorola ICS R1/2 SDK Add-on: For handset emulation" packages also available from http://developer.motorola.com/tools/resources/

> A Motorola SDK add-on, when added to the Android™ SDK, allows you to run and debug your applications on an emulated Motorola handset.

---

> Do I need them?

No, unless you want to do something specific to Motorola devices.

> Also, why doesn't Android 4.0.4 show up there?

4.0.4 is AFAIK just a bugfix release for specific devices but not a real standalone version. Devices running 4.0.4 will be compatible to 4.0.3 and use the same API level

Comment: Thanks! Strange that Google would prefix the `OpenSense SDK` with `HTC` but wouldn't prefix the `ICS_R1/R2` with `Motorola`.

Comment: The names are set by the 3rd party sites themselves and Motorola chose that confusing name. See http://android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com/addons.xml - I was confused too when I saw that package for the first time and disabled the addon sites (in `Tools`->`Manage Add-on Sites...`) :)

Comment: +1 Again for the tip regarding `Tools`->`Manage Add-on Sites...`.